# Does it matter whether you use lethal or non-lethal tactics in Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

Does it matter to the story?

Does it make a difference in the gameplay? E.g. with XP or whatnot.

Comment: Lethal is more funny, cuz even you use non-lethal tactics is hard to avoid the enemies and if they found you, you will wish have lethal weapons :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. According to the stealth tutorial video, a lethal takedown makes more noise than a non-lethal one.
2. Neutralizing an enemy without killing will award you a +20 XP bonus ("Merciful Soul").
3. Knocked-out hostiles can be woken by other people who happen to find them. Obviously, this can't happen if they're dead.

I'm not aware of any impact on the story, though there is a [Steam achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/DXHR/achievements) (*Pacifist*) for not killing anyone except bosses.

Comment: You get the Man Down XP for non-lethal takedowns, so it's actually a 20-XP difference.

Comment: You're right, thanks. @RavenDreamer, *I trusted youuuu*

Comment: @Lunboks - Guess it shows how many people I kill with non-lethal means.

Comment: There are some comments by characters if you go the non-lethal route.

Comment: Additionally, characters not killed can show up later in the story (see [To Kill or Not to Kill - Zeke in Deus Ex 3](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/to-kill-or-not-to-kill-zeke-in-deus-ex-3)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that enemies can only be woken up if they were knocked out with a takedown. I've not seen anyone taken out by tranq dart be woken up.

Comment: @Fambida, I've seen enemies be revived from takedowns, tranq darts and stun gun shots - basically it seems that if they're not dead they can be woken up.

Comment: @fambida: The only way to keep them from being woken is by doing a bang up job of hiding the bodies.

Comment: There is a very, very subtle change in dialogue depending on how many people you kill.

Answer (score 1):

you gain more experience when you do a non lethal takedown, the bonus is called Merciful Soul

> Merciful Soul: neutralize an enemy using non-lethal methods (20 XP)

There are also other types of xp bonus for every enemy you come across, see [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28789/what-actions-give-xp-in-deus-ex-human-revolution) for more information.

To maximize your experience, you will want to do as many double takedowns (none lethal) as possible and normal none lethal takedowns otherwise.

And killing enemies makes more noise where none lethal takedowns are virtually silent.

Answer (score 1):

there are some minor differences i noticed if you went non-lethal for the first mission and killed nobody the dialogues change the cops have nicer things to say and Maliks dialogue is also different